# Unable to download cordova component

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I got some problems with building cordova sample app, **AngularJSToDoApp**. 
I'm new to Cordova and I don't feel myself confident with this so it's hard for me to find a solution.

Here is the log:

```
1>  Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" via plugin registry
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD103: Error : DEP00103 : Unable to download Cordova component: http://cordova.iriscouch.com/registry/_design/app/_rewrite/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/-/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser-0.6.0.tgz
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD103: Error : DEP00103 : Unable to download Cordova component: http://cordova.iriscouch.com/registry/_design/app/_rewrite/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/-/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser-0.6.0.tgz
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD103: Error : DEP00103 : Unable to download Cordova component: http://cordova.iriscouch.com/registry/_design/app/_rewrite/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/-/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser-0.6.0.tgz
1>Failed to install 'com.microsoft.azure-mobile-services' : error : connect ETIMEDOUT
1>      at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
1>      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)
1>MDAVSCLI : error : connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Everything is alright with my internet connection and I tried to use android emulator and Ripple but still I have the same errors.

I will appriciate any help. I don't even know where I should start so it will be very nice if someone could tell me.

**OS:** Windows 10

**IDE:** Visual Studio Community 2015

**Project Link:** https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples

I did NOT change anything in a project. I just downloaded it and tried to build.

Comment: Could you provide some context preceding this?  What OS are you using?  What version of Visual Studio?  When you downloaded the sample app, did you make any changes?

Comment: @MichaelPalermo I added some details.

Comment: Thank you.  One more thing, can you please provide the exact link where you downloaded the sample from?

Comment: @MichaelPalermo done.

Comment: I would suggest using https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angularjs-cordova as another alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this project, mostly because it's just very old. It hasn't been updated since RC and still targets Cordova CLI 4.2.

The reason it's not building is because the plugin names have changed, and because they moved from git repos to NPM packages. The Cordova build can't find them.

I forked the repo and fixed the errors in this project. I'll submit a pull request. In the meantime, you can find my changes here:

https://github.com/mbraude/cordova-samples

I successfully got this project to build and deploy to Ripple in VS 2015 with the latest Cordova Tools (Update 4). I also added a bower.json file to the project and used that to pull in the JS references (which I manually copied to the scripts/frameworks directory).

Hope this helps at getting you started!

Answer (score 1):

The solution at the link you provided was created to work in the RC version of Visual Studio, and some references are out-dated.  Unfortunately the sample project has not been updated for 7 months.  So the answer is simple - it will not work in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Is Git is installed in you machine?
If not that please install is first from here,

Cordova adding plugin using command line tool

Before adding plugins to your application git command line tool is required.